# mathjax / mchem aligning

Tags: jquery, web, mathjax

i would like to ask how to align the text in to the one line? When I use

> $$\ce{H+}$$

it makes this:
[image: on new line, centered]

I would like to have the H+ in the same line. 
Does anyone have experiences with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
I have in script:

```
<script n:syntax="off" type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["[Contrib]/mhchem/mhchem.js"],
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["`","`"]]},
        showMathMenu: false,
        displayAlign: "left",

    });
</script>
```

So I should use `` :) My bad, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use single dollar signs, not double dollar signs.  I.e., `$\ce{H+}$`.